# Illustrator: how to avoid extra white space after export

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, transparency, file-format, clipping-mask

I am new to Illustrator and need to export artwork to JPG format, but getting some white space around the artwork when exporting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and adjust your artboard to only include the area you need to export
2. Do a `File → Save for Web` and uncheck the `Clip to Artboard` option.

[image]

Comment: thx for edited my question and and also for ur answer.i always export like this only file->export->save as -> then i choose PNG or Jpg to check the output is that a right way ?

Comment: Yes that is correct